# How to disable Camera and Screen Share for all applications (globally) in mac Using MDM?

Tags: macos, screen-capture, camera, mdm

We know that using MDM we can handle **Privacy Preferences Policy Control** in mac.

> I am able to disable **Screen Sharing** and **Camera feature** for the
> Particular Application.

Is there any way by which we can disable this globally for all applications?

[Payload Example](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mdm/mdm9ddb7e0b5/1/web/1)

[Device Management Profile](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/privacypreferencespolicycontrol/services/identity)

[PrivacyPreferencesPolicyControl.Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/privacypreferencespolicycontrol/services)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it. https://superuser.com/questions/1561945/how-to-disable-camera-and-screen-share-for-all-applications-globally-in-mac-us

Comment: @Tetsujin I agree with your point but I am looking for an answer to this. I get a comment from the developers to ask at superuser you might get an answer there that's why I asked there.

Comment: Which MDM are you using?

Comment: @TonyWilliams I am Creating this feature in Our Own MDM.

Answer (score 0):

The only MDM I currently have access to is Jamf Pro.

In Jamf Pro create a new configuration profile and in the left hand list select "Restrictions". Now in the main window select "Functionality" and the second and third items control the camera and screen recording.

[image: Main pane]

Comment: Using only this are you able to block Screen Sharing for all apps Like Zoom, Anydesk, Hangout, Chrome, Firefox, QuickTime?

Comment: You can also find this by creating a new configuration file with Apple Configurator. You do not have to be a supervised device to disable the camera.